# Listing instances next to each class in SPARQL query

Tags: format, sparql, instance, subclass

I want to write a SPARQL query that will give me a list that has all the subclasses of a specific class and all the instances of each subclass. E.g., if I have the class Animal with subclasses Dog and Cat and instances of Dog: Fido, Bowser and Cat: Fluffy, Whiskers I want the output to look like:

```
Dog  Fido Bowser

Cat  Fluffy Whiskers
```

I have a query to get all the instances of each subclass:

```
SELECT ?class_label ?instance_label
WHERE {?anmlclass rdfs:subClassOf ex:Animal;
                 rdfs:label ?class_label.
        ?anml a ?anmlclass;
               rdfs:label ?instance_label.}
```

But this gives output like:

```
Dog Fido

Dog Bowser
```

Is there a way to format the result so that all the instances are shown in the same row as the relevant class?

Comment: the only option is to use the aggregate function `group_concat`  - but, this will not produce as many "columns" as instances but a single string whose shape you can to some extend configure. Note, this operator also has some limitations like not necessarily keeping the order even when doing `order by`.

Comment: `SELECT ?class_label (group_concat(?instance_label; separator=", ") as ?instances)
WHERE {?anmlclass rdfs:subClassOf ex:Animal;
                 rdfs:label ?class_label.
        ?anml a ?anmlclass;
               rdfs:label ?instance_label.} GROUP BY ?anmlclass`

Comment: Thanks, that does what I need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67993535/listing-instances-next-to-each-class-in-sparql-query#comment120185349_67993535) by [UninformedUser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4744359/uninformeduser):

```
SELECT ?class_label (group_concat(?instance_label; separator=", ") as ?instances)
WHERE {
  ?anmlclass
      rdfs:subClassOf ex:Animal ;
      rdfs:label      ?class_label .         

  ?anml
      a          ?anmlclass ;               
      rdfs:label ?instance_label 
}
GROUP BY ?anmlclass
```